# Slack: saving my form as a custom workflow step in workflow builder

Tags: python, workflow, slack, slack-api

So the issue I am facing here is, I am trying to implement a solution where I have this form I am trying to implement in a workflow builder, so when I user accesses this form via a shortcut within a specific channel, they can fill in a request and the request gets posted in the channel for us to ack or mark as completed. The reason I am trying to enter the form within a workflow is because currently when a user submits the request via a manually created workflow, there is no data within the reaction_added payload to state who submitted that workflow initially so as you can see in the block of code under all the variable declaration I am grabbing the user_id via the conversation history which is not efficient.

So my issue is, when I chose my custom workflow step within the workflow builder the form shows up without an issue and returns a 200 response, but when I try to save that workflow step it just states Sorry, there was a problem trying to save your step but also returns a 200 response and there is no error output either. So I am curious what I am missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import re
from slack_bolt import App
from slack_sdk import WebClient
from slack_sdk.errors import SlackApiError
from slackeventsapi import SlackEventAdapter
from slack_bolt.adapter.flask import SlackRequestHandler
from flask import Flask, request, make_response
import json

SLACK_BOT_TOKEN = os.environ["SLACK_BOT_TOKEN"]
app = App(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)
client = WebClient(token=SLACK_BOT_TOKEN)
ack_emoji = "ack-party"
completed_emoji = "white_check_mark"
workflows = []
app = Flask(__name__)
slack_event_adapter = SlackEventAdapter(os.environ["SIGNING_SECRET"], '/slack/events', app)

channel_name = "abcdefg"
results = client.conversations_history(channel=channel_name)

for message in results["messages"]:
    if "Support-request-form" in message["text"]:
        timestamp = message["ts"]
        user_id = re.search("(?:<@)(.*)(>)", message["text"]).group(0)
        user_id = user_id[2:-1]
        workflows.append({"timestamp": timestamp, "user": user_id})

try:
    @slack_event_adapter.on('reaction_added')
    def reaction(reaction_payload):
        event = reaction_payload.get('event', {})
        reaction = event.get('reaction')
        user_reaction = event.get('user')
        workflow_ts = event.get('item', {}).get('ts')

        user_reaction_info = client.users_info(user=user_reaction)
        print(user_reaction_info)
        display_name = user_reaction_info.get('user', {}).get('profile', {}).get('display_name')
        real_name = user_reaction_info.get('user', {}).get('profile', {}).get('real_name')

        if reaction == ack_emoji:
            response = f"Your support ticket has been acknowledged by {real_name} ({display_name})"
        elif reaction == completed_emoji:
            response = f"Your support ticket has been marked as completed by {real_name} ({display_name})"

        for match_ts in workflows:
            if workflow_ts == match_ts["timestamp"]:
                message_user = match_ts["user"]
                client.chat_postMessage(channel=message_user, text=response)


    @app.route("/slack/events", methods=["POST"])
    def slack_events():
      handler = SlackRequestHandler(client)
      return handler.handle(request)


    @app.route("/workflows", methods=["POST"])
    def workflow_step():
        payload = json.loads(request.form.get("payload"))
        payload_data = payload.get('view') or payload

        callback_id = payload_data.get('callback_id')
        trigger_id = payload_data.get('trigger_id')
        if callback_id == 'open_prisma_support_request' and trigger_id:
            open_modal(trigger_id, callback_id)
        
        return make_response("", 200)

    def open_modal(trigger_id, callback_id):
        response = client.views_open(
            trigger_id=trigger_id,
            view= {
             "type": "workflow_step",
             "callback_id": callback_id,
              "blocks": [
                {
                    "type": "section",
                    "text": {
                        "type": "mrkdwn",
                        "text": "Type of Prisma Support Request",
                    },
                    "accessory": {
                        "type": "radio_buttons",
                        "action_id": "radio_buttons-action",
                        "options": [
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                    "text": "Issue",
                                },
                                "value": "Issue",
                            },
                            {
                                "text": {
                                    "type": "plain_text",
                                    "text": "Exception",
                                },
                                "value": "Exception",
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                },
                {
                    "type": "input",
                    "element": {
                        "type": "plain_text_input",
                        "action_id": "plain_text_input-action",
                    },
                    "label": {
                        "type": "plain_text",
                        "text": "Please fill in more details",
                    },
                },
            ],
                }
                )
        if response['ok']:
          print(response)
          
    @app.route("/workflows/submit", methods=["POST"])
    def submit_workflow():
        payload = json.loads(request.form.get("payload"))
        print(payload)
        return make_response("", 200)
    
    
except SlackApiError as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")

# {
#     "message_ts1": 
#         {
#             "ack_timestamp": "blabla",
#             "complete_timestamp": "Toto"
#         },

#     "message_ts2": 
#         {
#              "ack_timestamp": "blabla",
#             "complete_timestamp": "Toto"
#         },
# }

if __name__ == "__main__":
#debug=True if file modified, don't need to restart app.
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I have tried increasing the scope incase it was a permission issue, also the event subscription URL is set with the /slack/events suffix and the interactivity request url is set as /workflows. Right now the main thing I expect is being able to save my form as a workflow step, so users can access the custom workflow with a shortcut, fill in their request and the form will show up in the channel.